# Kotlin-Exposed : How to select a max timestamp

Tags: kotlin-exposed

New to the Jetbrains Exposed Framework here. I have an oracle table with 3 fields in it.

| ID | TIMESTAMP | FLAG |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | May1 12AM | Y |
| 1234 | May1 3PM | N |

I want to query the max timestamp row where FLAG = Y, but I'm not sure how to do this.

```
Employee.run {
    val results = select {(id eq employeeId) and (flag eq "Y")}
    // If no row with Flag = Y then I guess I can just return if results are empty          
    !results.empty()
}
```

I'm not sure how to check for a max timestamp in this.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up figuring out a way to do it. I'm sure there's a better way with both Kotlin and Expose.

```
fun Person.hasFlag(employeeId: String): Boolean {
    return transaction(db) {
        Employee.run {
            val results = slice(id, timeStamp, flag).select {(id eq employeeId)}.groupBy(id, timeStamp, flag)
            if (results.empty()) false else results.map {
                Pair(it[timeStamp], it[flag])
            }.maxByOrNull { m -> m.first }?.second == "Y"
        }
    }
}
```